# how to change sequence of ccnet file labeller

Tags: configuration, build, cruisecontrol.net

I have a ccnet project that uses a file labeller for reporting the build number. The problem is that the build process increments the value in this file, but the labeller event always occurs at the beginning of the build no matter where I sequence the task in the config xml file. I suspect that internally CCNET is processing the entire file and sequences certain events in a pre-defined order.

Is there a way to sequence this event to occur after the file has been updated? In my particular case I need to run a clean on all .NET projects before changing the value of the target file.

One thought I have but have never played with, is to create a project that cleans the VB.NET projects and updates the build number. Once this event has completed then the main project can kick off. This process would have to check for modifications for CI.

Perhaps someone has a better solution?

Thank you.
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I developed a solution by creating a separate BuildLabeller file and adding a powershell routine that just increments the build version value of that version number and then uses Set-Content to overwrite the file. The build labeller file will always be one value higher than the current build so that when the next build starts, it is the correct value for the file labeller task for ccnet.